# React App on Heroku responds to all requests with index.html

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I've been trying to fix an error in my application for days and am hoping for some help. I am able to run my app perfectly fine on my localhost, but when pushed to Heroku (React FE Node BE) I am able to navigate around my site, but GET/POST requests do not work. All of my get requests return my index.html file, and all of my POST requests (logging in mainly) return a 405 error "not allowed".

My app is hosted here: https://www.testofstrength.app
The codebase is here: https://github.com/mgitto1/test-of-strength/tree/New (within the "New" branch specifically.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The network tab does not show anything useful for your app. what do your server (heroku) logs say?

Comment: I don't think shows anything useful either, see below

2021-10-15T17:36:11.634661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/auth/login" host=www.testofstrength.app request_id=d9622262-d748-43f8-961c-388edcb833c7 fwd="96.57.2.162" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=405 bytes=712 protocol=https

2021-10-15T17:36:11.635930+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.56.234 - - [15/Oct/2021:17:36:11 +0000] "POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1" 405 552 "https://www.testofstrength.app/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

are you deploying both server and client on one dyno on heroku? you need different project structure...

server should be on root and client on separate folder

then in package.json of server in root you can have

```
 "scripts": {
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
"install-client": "cd ../client && npm install",
"start": "node server.js",
}
```